# Repository variable usage - How to track?

Tags: obiee, siebel

I have some older repository variables that I'm looking to turn off. Is there a good way to see where these variables are being used in reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think your best bet might be to search the Catalog using the file system. As the catalog objects are all stored as XML you can search them for the repository variables you have.

Comment: We are running windows server so I ended up going this route. Copied the repository files over to a local machine and searched. Little time consuming but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming you are on a Linux platform? You could create a test report using one of those variables (or all of them if you wish), and then run a `grep` command on the catalog in the database to spit out all reports that have that variable in them. I have done this on columns many times.

For example, I have a column named `Reporting Item Description` under the `- Product Details` folder. When anyone uses this column in OBIEE, this is how it is referenced in the catalog:

[image]

I would perform the following grep command that would spit out all reports (including their path in the catalog) that have that certain column (or in your case, variable):

`find ./ -type f -! -name "*.atr" -exec grep -l -e " - Product Details&quot;.&quot;Reporting Item Description&quot;" {} \;`

This same scenario should hold true for repository variables (or any variables).

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately we are not using Linux though.

Comment: Ah... I was afraid of that. Well I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. Cheers!